# two button reaction game using python3 and raspberry pi3

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi3, gpio

First post and and only been learning Python for 3 weeks...

I'm trying to create a game where 2 players have to wait for a buzzer sound connected to a breadboard and then press a button to see who is first.

This worked fine until I tried to add a method of keeping score. Now when the game runs the buzzer doesn't stop when the button is pressed and I get several error messages that repeat in the window. Can anyone help me to see what I've done wrong please?

```
from gpiozero import Button, LED, Buzzer
from time import time, sleep
from random import randint

led1 = LED(17)
led2 = LED(27)
btn1 = Button(14)
btn2 = Button(15)
buz = Buzzer(22)
score1 = 0
score2 = 0

btn1_name = input('right player name is ')
btn2_name = input('left player name is ')

while True:
    print(btn1_name + ' ' + str(score1) + ' - ' + btn2_name + ' ' + str(score2))
    sleep(randint(1,10))
    buz.on()
    def pressed(button):
        if button.pin.number == 14:
            print(btn1_name + ' won the game')
            score1 += 1
        else:
            print(btn2_name + ' won the game')
            score2 += 1
        buz.off()
    btn1.when_pressed = pressed
    btn2.when_pressed = pressed
```

The output messages are as follows

```
dave 0 - keith 0
keith won the game
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gpiozero/pins/rpigpio.py", line 232, in <lambda>
    callback=lambda channel: self._when_changed(),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 311, in _fire_events
    self._fire_activated()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 343, in _fire_activated
    super(HoldMixin, self)._fire_activated()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 289, in _fire_activated
    self.when_activated()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gpiozero/mixins.py", line 279, in wrapper
    return fn(self)
  File "/home/d.chilver/twobuttonreaction.py", line 26, in pressed
    score2 += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'score2' referenced before assignment
dave 0 - keith 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a problem of **scoping**. The two variables `score1` and `score2` are in the so called global scope. But you want to use them locally in a function. Python tries to create a local variable called `score1` or `score2` respectively by assigning a local variable `score1` or `score2` and then adding 1. Since the variable does not exist yet, you are subjected to the error message that you see.

In order to access the **global** variables you have to mark them explicitly like this:

```
[...]
def pressed(button):
    global score1
    global score2
    if button.pin.number == 14:
        print(btn1_name + ' won the game')
        score1 += 1
    else:
        print(btn2_name + ' won the game')
        score2 += 1
    buz.off()
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It was a big help. Just as a follow up... are global variables like my original ones bad practice? My next step is to stop the game accepting spam inputs. As it stands the player can hammer the button and receive a +1 score each time regardless of when the buzzer sounds. Any ideas would be a great help.

Comment: There is no problem with using global variables. Check out this gist: https://gist.github.com/NemoNessuno/1121acc79823f1d54dc83f8258118162 for some ideas regarding the input spam. Please note that I did not check the code because I'm at work right now, so if you encounter some problems please send me a message.